# Single word for agile, stealth, and light fingered

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word for agile, stealthy, and light fingered for a name of a skill in a game.

The only thing I could think of is the word 'finesse'.

> finesse
>
> fɪˈnɛs/ noun
>
> 1. impressive delicacy and skill.

Comment: Don't go looking for ***ninjas***, you'll never find them.

Comment: How about *fleet-footed*, or *fleet*, and the like?

Answer (score 3):

You could go for *nimbleness*, as [*nimble*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nimbleness) means:

> quick and light in motion, agile

Comment: *Nimble* doesn't really suggest stealth or being light fingered though.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for *sneaky*, defined by the [online M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneaky) as:

> marked by stealth, furtiveness, or shiftiness

This would descibe someone who can *sneak into* places, without being detected and, for example, steal something. I'm pretty sure I've seen a *sneak* skill in various games, actually.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you'll get is two out three, with @terdon's *Sneaky* maybe a two and a half. I like *[deftness](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deftness)* if you want to focus less on the light-fingeredness.

I was looking up *cat burglar* as a person that embodied all three, and came across the synonym *[sneak thief](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneakthief)*, which has a pleasing internal rhyme and could work for the name of a skill in a game.

Comment: *dexterous* if you *do* want to focus on the light-fingeredness.

Comment: I'm in support of *deft / deftness*.  I think it occupies a zone of meaning where the words agile, stealthy, and light-fingered often appear.  (And I assume you mean the second sense of "light-fingered", from [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/light-fingered), and not related to stealing.)  I also found this usage in a [1976 book by George Zollschan](https://books.google.com/books?id=0tK2AAAAIAAJ&q=deft+agile): "These people of the forest, moreover, are fleet of foot, **deft**, agile, and camouflage themselves well; they are dangerous to outsiders..."

Comment: @stevesliva, you made me think of the quote from Dr. Seuss: "Just never forget to be dexterous and deft."